# compiling embedded axis camera software using opencv. Make file changes

Tags: opencv, makefile, axis

I am developing and embed application for an axis camera.  I would like to use opencv with my project.  Currently, after running create-package.sh artpec-4, I received errors that it was skipping incompatible libraries, then it stooped once it couldn't find he first library that was incompatible.  I looked up this issue and one solution is to compile opencv using the new architecture.  If I included the source code for opencv in my project I think it could work. This would most likely be the best solution, because I don't know if I could get  opencv installed on the camera.
I have downloaded the opencv source files at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.6.1/opencv-2.4.6.1.tar.gz/download

essentially, I would like to know what files I will need from that .rar, where I should put them, and how to change the makefile to compile it all into a usable application.

here is my current main makefile

```
AXIS_USABLE_LIBS = UCLIBC GLIBC
include $(AXIS_TOP_DIR)/tools/build/Rules.axis

PROGS     = myapp

CFLAGS   += -Wall -g -O2
#CFLAGS   += -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2 
#LIBS     += -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
LDFLAGS  += -lnet_http -lcapture
ifneq ($(AXIS_OPT_DEBUG),y)
ifneq ($(AXIS_OPT_STATIC),y)
# Strip the binaries when building unless debug or static
# $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
LDFLAGS  += -s
endif
endif
SRCS      = myapp.cpp 

OBJS      = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all:    $(PROGS)

$(PROGS): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy

$(OBJS) : $(GENERATED_H)
# Install the package on the camera
install:        $(PROGS)
        create-package.sh
        install-onto-target.sh

clean:
        rm -f $(PROGS) *.o core
```

Comment: OpenCV does not use makefiles per se, it uses CMake to generate a makefile or project for MSVS or other programming environments. Also, OpenCV is quite big, so I think You don't want to include everything. Which parts would You like to include?

Comment: I would like to add CvCreateVideoWriter(), CV_FOURCC(), cvLoadImage(), cvWriteFrame(), cvReleaseVideoWriter().   I greped the folder I downloaded and found similar functions but not the same, for example cvVideoWriter_QT, and icvReleaseVideoWriter_QT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need core and highgui modules then (libopencv_core, libopencv_highgui).

Check [modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp) and [modules/highgui/src/cap.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/cap.cpp). In the second one there are procedures for most of functions You are looking for. The similar named functions are connected with fact, that OpenCV uses other libraries for video streams. If You are not going to use image processing capabilities of OpenCV it might be a better idea to take a look at libraries specialised in image/video reading and writing.